# Unexpected string in JSON at position <position> by sending a body with Postman

Tags: json, typescript, postman, backend

I am trying to implement the ability of the server to generate and validate JWT. I didn't have experience in TypeScript and Postman before so I got this error from the server:

```
json:  Unexpected string in JSON at position 26
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tep4.png) is the request I am sending with Postman

This is the function I use to generate JWT:

```
app.post("/generate", async (req, res) => {
        console.log("req.body: " + req.body)
        let body: any = await req.body;
        const  { name } = await body.value;
        let token = await generateUserJWT(name)
        res.json({ status: true, data: name, token:token });
    });
```

What is wrong with my request?

Comment: what are you sending in postman

Comment: @PDHide, https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tep4.png :)

Comment: What stack trace you are getting at server side , do you know at what point in code error is throwing?

Comment: What does console.log prints, why are you accessing body.value instead of body.name